# ios: Change the height of UIImageView with constraint inside UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, autolayout

in my app i am working on `UITableView` in which i am using `UIImageView` by setting up constraint on storyboard to display image. All i need is when there is no image available the height of `ImageView` will become 0 otherwise if image available height will be 150.

[image]

Comment: Then what is the issue ?

Comment: can you add a screenshot of that cell?

Comment: question updated

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya i dnt know how to set height constraint for uiimageview programmatically

Comment: You can add height constraint in storyboard and link that Height Constraint to IBOutlet NSLayoutContraint.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding constraints to left, top, right. Add a IBOutlet in your viewController for NSContraint for height. And when initialising cell check for image is available or not. Depending on that set the IBOutlet value.

Add that IBOutlet to your height constraint of UIImageView.

Set TableView cell height to automaticDimensions.

Let me know if it helps or having any issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. Give your ImageView to FixHeight Constraint
2. Create `IBOutlet` of that FixHeight Constraint

   @IBOutlet weak var imgviewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
3. in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`
   check this way

   ```
   if image available {
        cell.imgviewHeightConstraint.constant = 150
   } else {
        cell.imgviewHeightConstraint.constant = 0
   }
   ```

Comment: property imgviewHeightConstraint not found on object of type 'UITableViewCell'

Comment: you need to create  IBOutlet of that FixHeight Constraint. it not property

Answer (score 0):

1. In storyboard

   - Set your imageView constraint height `<= 150`
2. in `heightForR0w`

   - `return UITableViewAutomaticDimension`
3. in `estimateHeight`

   - `return 200`